# Probability of drawing a same color pair of socks "blindly" (in a dark room)

Tags: probability

This is a variation of a probability problem I had in college.

Suppose there are 10 different colored socks in a sock drawer in no particular arranged order, call the colors a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i and j.  The quantities of each of those colored socks are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10 respectively.  So for example, 1 sock of color a, 5 socks of color e, 10 socks of color j.

It is dark in a room so a person just grabs 2 socks at random without being able to see any of the colors of them.  However, because the person cannot see if the first pair is a match, he draws a 2nd pair of socks in an attempt to increase his chances of getting a matched pair.

Part 1) What is the probability that the person grabbed a pair of matching color socks if a match can only be made between socks 1 and 2, and/or socks 3 and 4.  For example, if the 4 socks drawn are b, c, b, d, then that is NOT a match since (b,c) and (b,d) are different pairs without a match within each pair.  It would have to be something like (b,b) and (c,d).  Also the and/or part covers situations such as (b,b) (c,c) which counts as 1 match (not 2).

Secondly, if ANY match counts (even across pairs), what then is the probability of getting at least one matched colored pair of socks in the 4 drawn?  In our previous b,c,b,d example, that WOULD be considered a matched pair because we have (b,b).  We are allowed to match any same colored socks of the 4 drawn, regardless of the order drawn.

I am not yet sure how to solve this mathematically, however a computer simulation of the first part of the question is showing about $21$% and the 2nd part is showing about $53.74$%

F.Y.I. 28 lines of code, about 10 million iterations (simulated random draws of 4 socks from 55 possible), to get the probabilities.

Also, one thing I noticed to help solve the first part... if we simplified it to be just drawing 2 socks and checking for a match, the correct answer should be 1/9 which is ($1 \choose 2$ + $2 \choose 2$ + ... + $10 \choose 2$) / $55 \choose 2$.  Then if we draw 2 more socks, we have the a similar expression, except over $53 \choose 2$, so that is $165/1378$. If you add those 2 together, you get about 23% which is pretty close to the simulation which gave 21%.  You would only have to subtract out the cases where you would get a matched pair in both the first and 2nd pair (so as to only count that match once, not twice).  For example, (b,b) (c,c) counts as a single match, not a double.

To approximate the 2nd part, we can again look at the much simpler example of only drawing 2 socks and get 1/9th probability of a match which is about 11%.  However if we instead draw 4 socks and allow any matched pair of them to count as a match, now we have $4 \choose 2$ different pairs to examine for that match, so a VERY rough approximation would be 6 times 11% = 66%.  Again we have to subtract out the cases where more than one match can occur (such as b,c,b,c or d,d,e,e...  Since more than one matched pair is more likely this way, the roughly 10% "correction factor" in the first part should be approximately doubled to 20% to account for this.

So using those we get 0.23 - 10% = 20.7% for the first part (pretty close) and .67 (rounded) - 20% = 53.6%  for the 2nd part (even closer).

These correction factors are not mathematical calculated, however they are more of a "feel" of how the numbers should be reduced.

Comment: I doubt that there's any way to do the first except by a laborious listing of possibilities.  If there isn't a match in the first pair, then we have to consider the case that the first two drawn were a and b, or a and c, or ....  The second one should be a straightforward, if tedious, application of inclusion and exclusion.  Besides considering the possibility of two pairs of different colors, you have to consider three and four socks of the same color.

Comment: So not an easy problems to solve mathematically either way?  I am trying a computer simulation to see if I can get a convincing and reasonable answer.

Comment: I don't think so. I could be wrong, but it seems like there are a lot of persnickety details to worry about.  A computer simulation makes more sense, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one (I am using Wolframalpha to simplify sums):

We have the following possibilities that yield positive outcomes:

1. We have four of the same color - No matter what order the socks are chosen, this yields a positive outcome
2. We have two distinct color socks - We can have a breakdown of 3 and 1 or 2 and 2. If the breakdown is 3 and 1, every outcome is positive. If the breakdown is 2 and 2, then only orders where we wind up with two pairs work.
3. We have three distinct colors of socks. Here, we need a matching pair plus a non-matching pair.

Suppose instead of 10 colors, we have $n$ colors, and we have $k$ socks of the $k$-th color. This means we have a total of $\dbinom{n+1}{2}$ socks. And the total number of ways to pick four socks is $$\dbinom{\binom{n+1}{2}}{4}4!$$

So, the total number of solutions in case 1:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dbinom{k}{4}4! = \dbinom{n+1}{5}4!$$

Case 2(a): 3 socks of 1 color, 1 sock of a second color:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n\left( \dbinom{j}{1}\dbinom{k}{3}+\dbinom{j}{3}\dbinom{k}{1} \right)4! = \dbinom{n}{2}\dfrac{5n^4-8n^3-13n^2+12n+12}{5}$$

Case 2(b): 2 socks of 2 colors each:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n \left(\dbinom{j}{2}\dbinom{k}{2}2!2!\right)2! = \dbinom{n}{3}\dfrac{2(5n^3+6n^2-2n-3)}{15}$$

Case 3: Choose two of 1 color and one of each other color, choose the position of the matching pair, then permute the two socks in each pair:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n \left(\dbinom{i}{2}\dbinom{j}{1}\dbinom{k}{1}+\dbinom{i}{1}\dbinom{j}{2}\dbinom{k}{1}+\dbinom{i}{1}\dbinom{j}{1}\dbinom{k}{2}\right)2!2!2! = \dbinom{n}{3}\dfrac{15n^4+10n^3-33n^2-34n-6}{15}$$

So, the total probability would be:

$$\dfrac{8 (3 n^3 + 10 n^2 - 7 n - 24)}{9 (n + 2) (n + 3) (n^2 + n - 4)}$$

Plugging in $n=10$ gives $$\dfrac{434}{2067} \approx 0.21$$

For the second problem, we have similar solutions for Case 1 and Case 2(a). For Case 2(b) and 3, instead of multiplying by 8, we multiply by $4!$. This gives a total probability (again, I just plugged the formulas into Wolframalpha) of:

$$\dfrac{8 (15 n^3 + 20 n^2 - 29 n - 48)}{15 (n + 2) (n + 3) (n^2 + n - 4)}$$

And plugging in $n=10$ gives:

$$\dfrac{5554}{10335} \approx 0.537$$

Note: Any time that I give a simplified sum, I just typed the original sum into Wolframalpha and it gives me a simplification. I am not justifying it beyond that.

Comment: Those answers match my simulations results, very impressive.  This seems like a pretty good (non trivial) math problem probably even challenging for math majors at college.  I made this problem up myself (well the variation part) as I have a pretty good "feel" for creating challenging problems of this type.  Glad you were able to solve it and very nice job.  I will give some other people time to "chime in" with alternative solution but if nobody else provides a good answer like this one, I will give you the checkmark for best answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Also it is very interesting to me that it is more likely than not that at least one matched pair of socks will be drawn by only choosing 4 out of the possible 55 socks. That is likely cuz the average number of socks of the same color is 5.5, and if the first sock chosen is color j (there are 10 of those colored socks), the chances are very high that at least one of the next 3 socks chosen will also be color j.  These type of problems are interesting cuz the answers sometimes surprise me.  Maybe next time, before I write the simulation, I should try to guess the answers and see how close I get.

Comment: It is true up to $n=11$ that the probability will be greater than 50%. So, with 66 socks, choosing 4, you still have a more than 50% chance of picking two matching socks.

Comment: Wow, but I think you meant at least 2 matching socks.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: One other comment is how someone with little to no math skills (but is decent at programming), can get the answer to this by running a simple simulation.  I have written MANY simulations of card games and problems like this sock problem.  This one was fairly easy to implement (28 lines of code).  It is so nice when we can see both a mathematical and a simulation solution agree.  It is also very interesting to see the mathematical solution and know it exists.  I've previously posted some even harder math problems and no exact answer was given on this site but some people got close.

Comment: Very good way of looking at it.  Much more organized than the way I was thinking about it.

Comment: saulspatz, why didn't you upvote my post for being creative?  I did not get this out of a book, it is my own concoction.  The remotely related problem we had in college was orders of magnitude simpler than this one.  They just asked what was the probability of drawing a matched pair of socks "blindly" and randomly from a drawer have 6 each of 3 colored socks (18 socks total).  That is very simple (5/17).  1st sock doesn't matter, 2nd one has only 5 matching socks left out of 17 total sock left.  That is like taking candy from a baby compared to this "monster" I created and that "probe" slayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at part 1.  As mentioned in the question itself, we can first solve a simpler problem which is drawing only 2 socks.  For that to match is ($1 \choose 2$ + $2 \choose 2$ + $3 \choose 2$ + ... + $10 \choose 2$) / $55 \choose 2$ which is 1/9.  Ok so we are halfway there (sorta).  Now we need to choose 2 more socks but it is not ($1 \choose 2$ + $2 \choose 2$ + $3 \choose 2$ + ... $10 \choose 2$) / $53 \choose 2$ because we have 2 less socks so if they were e and j, then we really have 1 less each of those, so instead of $5 \choose 2$ for e, we have $4 \choose 2$, and instead of $ 10 \choose 2$ for j, we have $9 \choose 2$.  Problem is, we "wont know" what first 2 socks are chosen if we are just computing the probability (and not doing an actual simulation).  So basically we would have to handle all cases where the first 2 socks are drawn, multiply (weight) it by how likely that is to happen, and compute the probability that way.  You could just do it "in order", such as assume the first 2 socks drawn are (a,b) and compute that partial probability, then next assume (b,b) was drawn, then (b,c)...  It is somewhat tedious but I think the correct exact answer can be gotten this way.  It would be great if someone tries it this way (or a better way if they can find one), and compare that result to the simulation results of about $21$%.